# Google Visualization API SETBACKS in financial applications

Tags: security, google-visualization

I did one small application for myself using Google Visualization API (Org Chart). I like it and now i feel this API help me to address one of the business use case. Please suggest me on following questions.
1. Is it advisable to have these Google Visualization API in financial applications.
2. Google Visualization API need any licensing for commercial usage purpose.
3. Since it is not an open source framework, i am unable to track or assume how Google Visualization API is using my application data to render the chart.

```
 a) Will it store the data that is being passed from my site?
 b) How secure my data if i pass key values to org charts to prepare and render the chart on my website page.
```

I sincerely request you to provide your valuable suggestions.

Sample Example (not actual code):

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
function drawChart(dataValues) {
            data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            data.addColumn('string', 'PlanName');
            data.addColumn('string', 'PaymentAmount');
            data.addColumn('string', 'ValidationId');
            data.addColumn('string', 'AccountName');

            for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
                data.addRow([{ v: dataValues[i].PlanName, f: dataValues[i].Name }, dataValues[i].AccountName]);



                }




            // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
            chart.draw(data, {
                allowHtml: true, allowCollapse: true, size: 'medium', explorer: {
                    maxZoomOut: 100,
                    keepInBounds: true
                }
            });
            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google Visualization API is fine for use within financial applications and is completely free, according to the [home page](https://developers.google.com/chart/).

And as stated in the **Data Policy** at the bottom of most every [example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart)...

> All code and data are processed and rendered in the browser. No data is sent to any server.

So your data is secure, from the standpoint it will not be exposed by the Google Visualization API.

The [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/terms/) apply to all Google APIs, not just the Visualization API...

Comment: Is Google logging all my chart data?"The chart data included in the HTTP request is saved in temporary logs for no longer than two weeks for internal testing and debugging purposes. Of course you should understand that if your chart appears in an image tag on a public webpage, it could be crawled." source:https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq". 2) http://www.google.com/jsapi i am thinking this file has some mechanism to send the data to google and prepare the chart and give it back to DOM (it is just a guess). Am i thinking it right

Comment: the faq link doesn't seem to work, but Google is not logging your chart data. `jsapi` is a JavaScript file that stores the code for the chart, this file is downloaded to the browser, runs on the browser, and any data fed to the api never leaves the browser.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq
can you please check this one. I went through Jsapi file i observer few http calls in the code. Frankly i didn't go over line by line to understand it. I request you to provide your inputs

Comment: Can any one help me providing answer for this ?

Comment: the only HTTP calls I'm aware of involve using dashboards and the chart editor. these features dynamically load the chart libraries needed based upon the charts used and user interaction. the last faq is confusing, it sounds like it is in reference to submitting charts to be displayed in the chart gallery. again, as stated on the examples --> _All code and data are processed and rendered in the browser. No data is sent to any server._